# Understanding proof why there can only be one triangle for $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, triangles

I'm following along the book "Basic Geometry" by Birkhoff and Beatley. It contains a proof for the Pythagorean Theorem:

> In any right triangle the square of the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the squares of the other two sides; and conversely.
>
> Given triangle ABC in which $\angle C = 90°$. To prove: $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
>
> ...
>
> Converse: Given lengths $a, b, c$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. To prove: there is one and only one right triangle having these lengths for sides.
>
> Proof: Construct a triangle ABC such that $AC = b$, $\angle C = 90°$ and $CB = a$.
>
> Then $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. (Why?)
>
> But $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$ (Given).
>
> Therefore $(AB)^2 = c^2$ and $AB = c$
>
> So there exists at least one right triangle with sides $a, b, c$. If more than one such triangle exists, these triangles must be equal, for it they are unequal, they violate Principle 8.

Principle 8 is SSS congruence.

I understand that if there is more than one triangle that fullfills $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ for the same $a, b, c$ then these triangles must be equal.

What I don't understand is why the converse proof from above shows that there is at least one such triangle.

Comment: You can explicitly construct the triangle.  Given $a,b,c$ with $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, this is saying: Construct a right triangle with leg lengths $a,b$.  Then the hypotenuse has length $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ by the Pythagorean theorem, which then must be your $c$, since by hypothesis $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.  So, you have a right triangle with lengths $a,b,c$.

Comment: @JairTaylor So as far as I understand, since we have three numbers $a, b, c$ which satisfy $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. Now we draw two legs of the triangle a, b and with a 90 degree angle between them. Deriving from what was given, we find that $c = sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ and now we know all three sides of the triangle. Thus this proofs that we can construct a right triangle from any $a, b, c$ if they satisfy $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ - is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claimed converse is the following statement: If the three sides of a triangle $\triangle$ satisfy $a^2+b^2=c^2$ then the triangle has a right angle at $C$.

For the proof we draw an auxiliary right triangle $\triangle'=A'B'C'$ with $|A'C'|=b$, $|B'C'|=a$, and a right angle at $C'$. There is no question that such a triangle exists. Using the already proven part of Pythagoras' theorem we then can say that $|A'B'|^2=a^2+b^2=c^2$, hence $|A'B'|=c$. This shows that $\triangle'$ has the same side lengths as $\triangle$. By "Principle 8" it is then congruent to $\triangle$. This implies that the angles are equal as well; in particular the angle at $C$ is $90^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that if $a,b,c$ are positive numbers such that $c < a + b$ (where $c$ is the largest of the three) then there is a triangle with sides $a,b,c$?

Then you can see that if you have $a,b,c$ with $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ then $c^2 < a^2 + 2ab + b^2 = (a+b)^2$, so there is such a triangle.

Comment: I think that rule is only derived later in the book as a corollary. I'm mainly stuck at this line "Then $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. (Why?)" because I can't answer that question _Why?_

Comment: You can construct a triangle with sides $a$ and $b$ that has a right angle between them, right? Then, by the Pythagorean theorem, the third side must be $c$ such that $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$.

Comment: @Max $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ is true by hypothesis - you are given $a,b,c$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.  So it does not need justification.  I don't know why they would include the parenthetical (Why?) in this case - it makes me wonder if there was an error in the transcription or the original text.